# Eclipse does not work after update through Android SDK Manager

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I have just updated my eclipse through Android SDK Manager, my eclipse pop out and error about the Android SDK.

> This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.
>   Current version is 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508

When I pressed the button "Check for Updates", the result from eclipse is "No Updates were found."

I am sure that my Android SDK should be 23.0.0 above.
[image: Android SDK]

All my project listed in the left corner of above picture contains errors.
I have studied this thread and I found that the "Java build path" was "Unable to get system liberary for the project"

[The project was not built since its build path is incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341644/the-project-was-not-built-since-its-build-path-is-incomplete)

Whenever I tried to add the JRE System Library, it failed beacause of "Could not write file: C:\Users\Admin\workspace\ICEAPP(20140819_uc).classpath."

Can anyone give me so help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.6.1 or above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524789/error-this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-22-6-1-or-abo)

Comment: this question already has a solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-v-23

Answer (score 0):

Update the ADT-Plugin in eclipse (Help > Check for updates)

Comment: I tried but there were no updates. It to the same as clicking the "Check for Updates" button.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the whole installation and reinstall everything again. This update seems to fail always. But reinstall works for all of this issues. With the new version 23. It seems there is a big compatibillity problem unsolved yet.

Check for updated fails but eclipse say it need one update. Also SDK Manager seems to be up to date.

Anyway, even if you get ot working, there still are  problems for example with implementation of google play service.

Had a lot of issues by myself and others to, but reinstall solved it

Comment: Hello, I would like to ask how I can completely remove the eclipse? Just delete the whole ADT folder?

Comment: @Hello yes, just remove the folder ( or rename it) and unpack the actual adt-bundle again. Unfortunately you have to download/install everything again also from SDK-Manager