# how to configure android SDK with eclipse luna in ubuntu?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu, configuration

I have download eclipse luna  then after i have doenload android-sdk-linux then after I have run `tools/android update sdk --no-ui` this command what next step I have done so I develop android application in my eclipse.

I have try to import my old android project this gives errors like:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project    google-play-services_lib        Unknown Java Problem
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project    gu10science     Unknown Java Problem
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    TestActivity.java   /gu10science/src/com/sparrow/gu10science    line 1  Java Problem
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    UnusedStub.java /google-play-services_lib/src/android   line 1  Java Problem
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but you really should consider using Android Studio as it is now the official Android IDE supported by Google. http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: previous i have development in eclipse so now i prefer development in eclipse please give reply how to ateach and configure the android sdk

Answer (score 1):

You can get your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9341736/1974306

> (...) select Android API version (set to another one and valid, then restore the on you want and validate it -> it will force Eclipse to reload API). (...)